# Choosing the axis of rotation

Tags: geometry, raytracing

I have a cylinder whom the orientation vector is (1, 1, 0).
I want to rotate it so that its orientation vector becomes (0, 1, 0).
How can I define the axis around which to rotate?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you use quaternions?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate rotation axis direction as [vector product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation) of initial and final orientation. Here

```
R = A x B = (0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @MBo
Tho how one should interpret the resulting vector?

Comment: Emm...  You wanted to find rotation axis - here it is.   Resulting vector (axis direction) is perpendicular both to initial and to final vector.

Comment: What would that mean in terms of rotation matrices to apply?
I have tried with R as (R_z * R_y * R_x) and it didn't work. From where my question.